# Entity Framework Core Assign role to user after created

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2, entity-framework-core-2.2

i would like to know how can i associate a specific role to a user when he is created

I have this on my create User page

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }


        _context.Users.Add(User);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        _toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Utilizador Adicionado com sucesso");

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

I have tried on the model

```
    public User()
    {
        IsActivo = true;
        UserRoles.Add(new UserRole { RoleId = 4 });
    }
```

this does not work unfortunely.

Answer (score 1):

For both users and roles you should be using the associated managers: `UserManager<TUser>` and `RoleManager<TRole>`. There's a number of things that need to happen besides simple persistence that the managers handle and that adding directly to the context does not. Here, though, you only need `UserManager<TUser>` to handle everything.

```
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public RegisterModel(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    await _userManager.CreateUserAsync(User);
    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(User, "foo"); // where "foo" is the name of your role

    _toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Utilizador Adicionado com sucesso");

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

Comment: Problem is that i am not using identity framework so i cannot user usermanager

Comment: What do you mean? Are you rolling your own auth? If so, then there's no way to reasonably answer your question, as it's your code, so only you would know how to associate a role. However, you should not roll your own auth. You will screw it up. That's not an indictment of you. Auth is hard. Identity is battle-hardened; your code is not.

Comment: i am just using cookieauthentication, I tried identity many times and i don't like all the generated columns, plus the need to store password cause we use LDAP for authentication on our intranet. It takes a lot of work to write down all custom storages

Comment: What does that have to do with anything. The point is the whole user/roles/claims/etc. management. Not only are you reinventing the wheel, but you're inventing an inferior wheel.

Comment: well then, if you can recommend me an actual useful tutorial  how to customize without implementing all storage providers maybe i would change my mind about it

Comment: The stores are just for tying it to a persistence mechanism. You're already using EF Core, so there's already default stores - no need to implement anything. Not sure what you're wanting to customize, but that really has nothing to do with the actual stores.

Comment: I mean, i would like to be able to add relations to the users table, delete useless columns, change primary key to int etc...

Comment: All of that is easily customizable. The docs cover most of it. The one exception might be removing columns, depending on the column. Useless to you and useless to Identity are two separate matters.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I took some time rereading entity framework tutorials and this worked for me

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
   {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }


        _context.Users.Add(User);
        _context.UserRoles.Add(new UserRole { User = User, Role = _context.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Nome == "User")});

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        _toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Utilizador Adicionado com sucesso");

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```